# How can the client display the server's progress during a remote DCOM call?

Tags: delphi, progress, dcom, multi-tier, remote-process

I have an multi tier application witch use a TDcomConnection on the client side and a TRemoteDataModule on the Server side.

I have published a process server, which reads a TSQLQuery.

When I call this procedure from the Client application through DComConnection, the client application does not respond until the procedure on the server have not finished.

I've resolved the blocking using threads on the client application to call the procedure on the server application.

But I need to show a TProgressBar on the client application which shows the procedure's progress on the server side

I don't know how can access to the server in the same session while other function is working

Comment: So, you're asking how can you make the server report its progress to the client while it's processing something time consuming? I'm guessing you may need to separate this into two connections - one for commands/controls and the other for data transmission. Then again, I've never used the components you're speaking of and there may be a simple switch for this, although I doubt it due to its nature.

Comment: TDCOMConnection is a DataSnap component (earlier version), right?

Comment: Does the client side app use a TClientDataSet to fetch a SQL result set, or does it only call a server method and the result set is only fetched on the server side?

Comment: Which SQL server?  This is rather important... http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63122 ;  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3289670/327083  ;   http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/76556/progress.pdf  ;  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3328/sql-server-2014-real-time-query-monitoring/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/129437/327083  ;  http://stackoverflow.com/q/15938040/327083 ;  http://stackoverflow.com/q/5464931/327083 ... I mean, it just goes on and on.  The search box is a gold mine.

Comment: Not clear, however, if "the server" refers to your server or if it refers to the SQL server?  I'm guessing these are different... you have a client <-> server <-> SQLServer?  Are you having problems with the client <-> server part or the server <-> SQLServer part?

Comment: @mjn thanks, I'm using Delphi XE3 to deploy the applications... The client application has a TClientDataSet, but only for fetch a result set, But is the procedure in the server application which use those result set... The client application calls that procedure and it does not do any action additional... Thanks

Comment: @J... Hi, I apologize, I not been clear, I refer server like an application, not a database server, my application has a client-server-DBServer, what I need is a way to know the progress of the procedure in the server application